# SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed: 550 5.7.1 Mail contain spam content 92AEB60013

Tags: php, html

I created an email notification after the data is entered into the database in php but I get an error, I'm using the titan email configuration.

This the code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.titan.email";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "info@ujicoba.co.id";
$mail->Password = "Mereka5678";
$mail->setFrom('info@ujicoba.co.id', 'Karyawan');
$mail->Subject = "Pengajuan Lembur Baru";
$mail->Body = $isipesan;
$mail->addAddress('info@ujicoba.co.id');

 if(!$mail->Send()) 
 {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
//Jika Sukses
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: If that's your actual user name and password you should change them immediately.

Comment: Sorry. Just a sampel username and password